# How can I 1 to a variable for every time someone clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cookies, addition

I have this algorithm to calculate the average of votes which is: (a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e + 6f + 7g + 8h + 9i + 10j) / (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j)

But the problem is that I want to add one to a variable for every click someone clicks and display the average after reload.

```
ex:. a = 25 //the amount of people who voted "1";
     b = 19 //the amount of people who voted "2";
     c = 78 //the amount of people who voted "3";
     d = 98 //the amount of people who voted "4";
     e = 69 //the amount of people who voted "5";
     average = (a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e + 6f + 7g + 8h + 9i + 10j) / (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j);
     alert(average); // Alerts 3,5
```

*Someone clicks "d", and ten other people click "e"*

```
 adds +1 to "d"

 adds +1 to "e" (10x)

 alerts the new average on reload.
```

Thats what I want it to do but I don't know how to work with cookies (if its necessary)

Comment: why are the choices in the numerator being multiplied? That's not how averages work

Comment: I hope you realize this will only change the person's browser and not across every person that hits your site. First step, learn how to set a cookie or local storage. Plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: You will need a database or some sort of server side storage to make this consistent across all users. Is that what you want?

Comment: @jbabey Yes, but in my case i'm trying to the average of the rating not the average amount of people who voted.

Comment: oh, it is a weighted average. that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just creating this single web page to allow people to vote then you can simply do it all in memory by not refreshing the page like as if every single voter is coming to this computer and placing their vote. That is like asking all your voters to come to your computer and place the vote.

It is a strange question because typically if you are allowing people to use your web page from different client browser ( their computers ) then you need some other server side mechanism to keep track of the votes. Cookies will be different for each client and will not work. May be use PHP as server side language for keeping track of votes on the server.